# Spring Data JPA - Error counting elements of a table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this JPA Query:

```
@Query("select count(de) from DeviceEvent de left join de.deviceMessage dm where dm.level = AlarmLevelEnum.HIGH order by de.dateReceived desc ")
    int numDeviceEventsWithAlarm ();
```

but when I run the query I got this message:

```
2020-05-26 18:46  [http-nio-5678-exec-1] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 90016, SQLState: 90016
2020-05-26 18:46  [http-nio-5678-exec-1] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - La columna "DEVICEEVEN0_.DATE_RECEIVED" debe estar incluida en la lista de GROUP BY
Column "DEVICEEVEN0_.DATE_RECEIVED" must be in the GROUP BY list; SQL statement:
select count(deviceeven0_.id) as col_0_0_ from t_device_event deviceeven0_ left outer join t_device_message devicemess1_ on deviceeven0_.device_message_id=devicemess1_.id where devicemess1_.level=2 order by deviceeven0_.date_received desc [90016-200]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `order by` part of your query is unnecessary because you need only a total `count` of rows.

So, you should correct your query in this way:

```java
@Query("select count(de) from DeviceEvent de left join de.deviceMessage dm where dm.level = AlarmLevelEnum.HIGH")
int numDeviceEventsWithAlarm ();
```